# Request resource from a URL and then discard it

Tags: php, api

I'm having to work with this crazy third party API where if you request an image from it, and specify it to be of certain size dimensions, you get given the URL of that image back which you then need to download/request fully and the API *then* does the image transformation and *then* the next time you request that image via the API, it returns a new URL where the image has been transformed.

I'm trying to work out how to automate this and am not sure how to request this image and effectively download it but discard it so that the API is triggered to transform the image so that on my next request, it gives me the new URL.

I have been trying the following code to request the image, but this doesn't seem to trigger the API into action, so I guess I may have to completely download the image to make it trigger the process. I don't want to "keep" these images though, just download and discard I guess.

```
$url = "https://example.co.uk/media/blahblah.jpeg";
$parts=parse_url($url);
$fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],443,$errno, $errstr, 30);
$out = "GET ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
$out.= "Content-Length: 0"."\r\n";
$out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
var_dump($out);
fwrite($fp, $out);
fclose($fp)
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: do I understand correctly that you need to do 3 requests to get the final image?

Comment: Where do you imagine your current code to be "keeping" the images ...? You are just making an HTTP request, but unless you explicitly store the result somewhere on your server, nothing is "kept" anywhere.

Comment: @JanMyszkier Yep, it's absolutely crazy. Also, you don't know *how* long the API will take to transform those images, so you kind of have to wait an hour before doing the final requests to be certain all the images have been transformed.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah I guess, but it's certainly not triggering the API to make the transform!

Comment: That could be due to the use of fsockopen, I suppose - you are opening the connection, but then you are not actually reading any response data. Why did you chose fsockopen to begin with here, and not simply file_get_contents (or if that is blocked on the server, cURL)?

Comment: @CBroe I guess I just didn't really want to download anything as there are *loads* of images and I want this process to run quickly. I was trying to just trigger the API to read a initial request for the asset in the hope that was enough to trigger the next step at their end.

Comment: But you did say yourself that the image needed to be downloaded/requested "fully", for the API to trigger the next step ...?

Comment: @CBroe It's an assumption after running my code and not getting the desired results.

Comment: It depends on how the service works, the transformation can stop after you close the connection, you may ask the developer for help.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

url from the first request is returned as text, not JSON

target url for the image stays the same after the first request is made

result image is always a jpeg

```
<?php

$firstUrl = 'https://example.co.uk/media/blahblah.jpeg?width=100&height=100';
$imageUrl = file_get_contents($firstUrl);

//touch transformUrl, do not download anything yet
requestImageTransformation($imageUrl);

//@FIXME: wait 1 second to let the transformation api transform the image in the background. Should check the response headers of $imageUrl 
sleep(1);

//downloadUrl
$imageData = file_get_contents($imageUrl);

///now save the new image to disk
file_put_contents('my_transformed_image.jpeg', $imageData);

function requestImageTransformation($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array([
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'HEAD'
    ]);

    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

That should at least get your going.